# Significance of mixed-effects model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I currently have some mixed-effects models and I am unsure which one to use, and how to determine significance of them. Possibly a small issue I am having as i am confused which model gives me results that I want.

```
1. lmer(score ~ (case+gender+age+test)^2 + (1 | CASE.NO), data = temp)

2. lmer(score ~ case+gender+age*test + (1 | CASE.NO), data = temp)
```

This is an example, I am interested in looking at whether age interacting with which test someone took is significant. However, when i run both of these models, they give different significance results for age interacting with test while controlling for gender and case. Should i be using the #2? Or is #1 the correct way to do this?

Comment: Models are generally not set up to "give you the results that you want", they are set up to answer the research questions you are interested in - the answers may or may not conform to what you want, depending on the nature of your data. So what are your research questions? In particular, do you have any pre-defined hypotheses about the interactions in your model?

Comment: Well I am hoping to see whether certain test are affected by age significantly in relation to score. I am assuming atleast some of them do as they are IQ type examinations. However, I want to control for whether they are a case subject (mental illness or not) and whether they are male or female.

Comment: #2 seems like the model you want.